# graph f is connected and closed in $\mathbb{R} ^{2}$ if and only if, graph f is closed in $\mathbb{R} ^{2}$ and it has intermediate value property.

Tags: analysis

Graph $f$ is connected and closed in $\mathbb{R} ^{2}$ if and only if, graph $f$ is closed in $\mathbb{R} ^{2}$ and it has intermediate value property.

I've done the proof for one side:

> If $f$ is connected and closed in $\mathbb{R} ^{2}$, for any $(y, f(y))$ and $(x, f(x))$ in the graph, for any point $(z, f(z))$ such that $(x, f(x)) < (z, f(z)) < (y, f(y))$, just because graph $f$ is connected in $\mathbb{R} ^{2}$, then $(z, f(z))$ exists.
>
> also, graph $f$ is closed in $\mathbb{R} ^{2}$ and it implies that the image of $(z, f(z))$ is closed on axis $X$.
>
> thus, for any z such that $x<z<y$, $f(z)$ exists.

Is my proof wrong?
Or any other idea about how to prove this?

Comment: Could you please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your questions? You're already doing it when you write $\Bbb{R}^2$; it would make it look nicer if you placed `$` signs around the other maths expressions. Also, instead of using multiple """ to denote quotes, try using `>` at the beginning of the line to form a blockquote.

Comment: @user804886 allright, done. thanku.

Comment: Thank you for doing that. I submitted a suggested edit that might improve things slightly.

Answer (score 1):

To put it bluntly, no, your answer is not right and has several issues.

I think the most important issue is that you're not making the logic clear in general. You refer both to connectedness and closedness, but I don't actually see how you actually use these concepts. Indeed, it's not even clear to me from this proof that you know what these terms mean! The only property of which I'm confident you know the definition is the intermediate value property.

I also want to point out that you seem to have a habit of working with a quantity (e.g. $(z, f(z))$) in an argument, then concluding that this quantity exists. This is not valid, simply because by using something in an argument like this, you are assuming it exists in the first place, and concluding its existence is a circular argument.

Before I move on, I finally want to say that $(x, f(x)) < (z, f(z)) < (y, f(y))$ is not well-defined notation. Are you simply saying $x < z < y$, and if so, then why not state it as such (it's not like it's any longer to write out)?

To actually prove this result, you'll need to know (and use) the definitions of "connected" and "closed" (although, for this direction, "closed" is not really so important). You need to prove the intermediate value property, so let's suppose we have $a < b$ such that $f(a) \neq f(b)$ (without loss of generality, let's suppose $f(a) < f(b)$, as if it were instead $f(b) < f(a)$, then we can replace $f$ with $-f$ and the graph will still be connected). Further, suppose that $q \in (f(a), f(b))$. We have to **prove** a point $c \in (a, b)$ exists such that $f(c) = q$.

As I said, we'll need connectedness. How can we use connectedness? If we can find two disjoint open sets $\mathcal{U}, \mathcal{V} \subseteq \Bbb{R}^2$, each of which intersect the graph of $f$, then they cannot cover the graph of $f$. That is, if $\mathcal{U} \cap \operatorname{Graph} f \neq \emptyset \neq \mathcal{V} \cap \operatorname{Graph} f$, then there exists some $(c, f(c)) \in \operatorname{Graph} f \setminus (\mathcal{U} \cup \mathcal{V})$. We want to choose our open sets in such a way that guarantees $f(c) = q$.

Here's a naive (but incorrect) idea: what if $\mathcal{U} = \{(x, y) : y > q\}$ and $\mathcal{V} = \{(x, y) : y < q\}$? Since $f(a) < q$ and $f(b) > q$, then $(a, f(a)) \in \mathcal{U} \cap \operatorname{Graph} f$, and $(b, f(b)) \in \mathcal{V} \cap \operatorname{Graph} f$, proving both sets are non-empty. Therefore, there must exist some $c$ such that $(c, f(c)) \in \operatorname{Graph} f \setminus (\mathcal{U} \cup \mathcal{V})$, which can only happen if $f(c) = q$.

Why is this idea wrong? We have no idea whether $c \in (a, b)$ or not! But, we're on the right track. Instead, consider the slightly more complicated open sets:
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{U} &= \{(x, y) : x < a \text{ or } (x < b \text{ and } y < q)\} \\
\mathcal{V} &= \{(x, y) : x > b \text{ or } (x > a \text{ and } y > q)\}.
\end{align*}
If this is confusing, try drawing a diagram (sketch a non-constant continuous function, pick appropriate $a$ and $b$ as you like so that $f(a) < f(b)$, and pick $q$ between them). The two open sets are on either side of a crooked line, which moves vertically down the line $x = a$ until it reaches $y = q$, then moves horizontally along $y = q$ until it reaches $x = b$, then moves vertically down again along $x = b$. Hopefully this makes it clear that $\mathcal{U} \cap \mathcal{V} = \emptyset$.

Again, we have $(a, f(a)) \in \mathcal{U}$, since $a < b$ and $f(a) < q$. Similarly, $(b, f(b)) \in \mathcal{V}$. We therefore have some $(c, f(c)) \notin \mathcal{U} \cup \mathcal{V}$. Note that we cannot have $c < a$, otherwise $(c, f(c)) \in \mathcal{U}$, and we can't have $c > b$, otherwise $(c, f(c)) \in \mathcal{V}$. We also obviously can't have $c = a$ or $c = b$, since the points $(a, f(a))$ and $(b, f(b))$ belong to the $\mathcal{U}$ and $\mathcal{V}$ respectively.

So, $c \in (a, b)$. We just need $f(c) = q$. In order for $(c, f(c)) \notin \mathcal{U}$, we must have $c \ge a$ and ($c \ge b$ or $f(c) \ge q$). We already know that $c < b$, so this means that $f(c) \ge q$. Similarly, from seeing that $(c, f(c)) \notin \mathcal{V}$, we get $f(c) \le q$. Therefore, it follows that $f(c) = q$.

Thus, in total, we have found a point $c \in (a, b)$ so that $f(c) = q$, proving that $f$ has the intermediate value property.

This answer is long enough, and you did only ask about one direction. See if you can use the closedness of the graph and the intermediate value property to show the graph is connected.